# How to copy and paste react app URI and return the correct page?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I have a simple front-end React app with no back-end. I want to be able to open a new tab with a given URI and be able to return the correct page with results. I'm using react-router-dom v5 for routing:

```
<Router>
   <Route exact path="/" render={/* component with props*/}/>
   <Route path="/search" render={/* component with props*/}/>
   <Route exact path="/search/:name" render={/* component with props*/}/>
   <Route exact path="/search/:name/artist=:selection/albums" render={/* component with props*/}/>
</Router>
```

In the app if i searched in the search bar for "jason", results would show among others, and I could click on "jason aldean". When I click jason aldean, the URI is: "http://localhost:3000/search/jason/artist=jason%20aldean/albums". I want to be able to copy and paste that same link in a new tab and show the exact same results.

In order to even get results, my app gets an access token from spotify's API. This is handled in the "/" route (login button triggers spotify login). Once login is complete, /search will be rendered with the access token in the URI, then I render /search without the access token in the URI, but saved in the app.

In short what needs to happen when copying a URI in a new tab is:

1. Redirect to spotify's login to retrieve access token
2. Redirect to "/search"
3. Redirect based off of the URI params